# Python: Why does tkinter not execute a procedure despite it being called on within the button?

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()
main.wm_title("Flashcards")

terms = []
defs = []
count = 0

configuration = tk.Frame(bg = "sky blue")
configuration.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

flashcards = tk.Frame(bg = "sky blue")
flashcards.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
flashcard = tk.Button(flashcards, font = ("Dotum", 12))
finish = tk.Label(flashcards, font = ("Dotum", 24), border = 10)

def createflashcard():
    terms.append(ent_term.get())
    defs.append(ent_def.get())
    ent_term.delete(0, "end")
    ent_def.delete(0,"end")

def studyset():
    global count
    global finish
    global flashcard
    if count == 0:
        finish.pack_forget()
    flashcards.tkraise()
    flashcard.pack(side = "top")
    configuration.grid_forget()
    flashcard.configure(text = terms[count], command = replaceflashcard)
    print(terms)

def replaceflashcard():
    global count
    global flashcard
    global finish
    flashcard.configure(text = defs[count])
    if count == (len(terms) - 1):
        finish.pack(side = "top")
        finish.configure(text = "End of Set!")
        flashcard.configure(command = endset)
    else:
        count = count + 1
        flashcard.configure(command = studyset)

def endset():
    global count
    global finish
    global flashcard
    flashcard.configure(text = "Restart set", command = studyset)
    count = 0

ent_term = tk.Entry(configuration, text = "Enter your term", font = ("Dotum", 12))
ent_term.pack(side = "top")

ent_def = tk.Entry(configuration, text = "Enter definition", font = ("Dotum", 12))
ent_def.pack(side = "top")

create = tk.Button(configuration, text = "Create 
flashcard", font = ("Dotum", 12), command = createflashcard)
create.pack(side = "top")

studyset = tk.Button(configuration, text = "Study set", font = ("Dotum", 12), command = studyset)
studyset.pack(side = "top")

main.mainloop()
```

I am attempting to write a program that allows you to create flashcard sets. When studying the flashcards, the tkinter program packs a button which the user can click on to switch from the term to its definition. When the user clicks on the button again, the program is meant to switch to the next term in the list.
The program runs as it should up until count is incremented within the replaceflashcard() function. It doesn't execute the studyset() function as I coded in. I click the flashcard button repeatedly yet it stays stuck displaying the definition.

Comment: It is because you used same name `studyset` for both function and Button.  The Button override the function.  Use another name for the Button.

Comment: @acw1668 ohhhh tysm man.